# SharePoint 2013 Search: Create schedule interface issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, crawling, sharepoint-search

When I try to create schedule either for incremental or full crawl I get the following interface that looks kinda corrupted as shown below:

[image]

Notice that the html `<b> Select rights </b>` tag. If I compare it with a other working interface it, the button with the `<b> Select rights </b>` tag suppose to be the **OK** button. Here is what the create schedule suppose to look:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have some customization or something wrong in your browser. Please try browse with another PC's browser or check with F12 tool for any customization is in action.

Beside, you can setup your crawl schedule with PowerShell. Please check with MS [reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spenterprisesearchcrawlcontentsource?view=sharepoint-ps).

This example returns the "Local SharePoint Sites" content source and creates a schedule to run a full crawl every 30 days and an incremental crawl every hour every day.

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$cs = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -Identity 'Local SharePoint Sites' -SearchApplication $ssa
$cs | Set-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -ScheduleType Full -DailyCrawlSchedule -CrawlScheduleRunEveryInterval 30
$cs | Set-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -ScheduleType Incremental -DailyCrawlSchedule -CrawlScheduleRepeatInterval 60 -CrawlScheduleRepeatDuration 1440
```